# Spring Boot+ Scheduled Method+OutOfMemory GC overhead limit excedded

Tags: spring, out-of-memory, scheduling, boot

I am using spring boot application which run through bat file.This i am using for many background services which interact with database and create txt files etc. All methods are annotated with @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${fixedDelay}") here fixedDelay=2000.

As many @Scheduled annotation that many thread i have configured through application.properties file. There is one method which basically call three mssql database procedure and i have to wait for all three procedure response and then proceed further. For this i have used Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3) and wait for response by future.get() this is a long running process that might take 2 or 3 hr or even more. Now i am getting Outofmemory GC overhead limit exceeded.First i try to increase the heap size but still this issue comes. And one i see the heapdump, i found outofmemory comes in this Method execution.Is there some limitation that we can not call any sql statement that will take more then 3 hr or more through thread?

I took the heapdump but from that i am not able to get the root cause. Because i am just calling the procedure in this.Not doing any other operation.Please help in this.Heap dump image is attached

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Please let me know if some one has any clue on above. Meanwhile i am trying to change approach. Means just call all three procedures from three different thread and will wait for timeout for response. Then will terminate the thread. If there are issue with response time for thread that are taking 2 or 3 hrs.

Comment: Hi All Please help if any one has any input on above heapdump. it's still coming and at the same thread. It's urgent.